# Why is v2/api-docs the default URL when using springfox and Swagger2?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I'm just starting using swagger following this [guide](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api), but I found out something very weird that makes no sense for me.

As far as I remember , the v2/api-docs should be used for when you have docs of the version number 2 of your API.

So, the default should be only api-docs, but for some strange reason I found that the default is v2/api-docs.

Checking the library doc I found [this](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#swagger-1-2-vs-swagger-2-0).

How do I override that value without later not being able to use v2? (when my API will reach a v2 but I will also want to show the legacy docs).

Or maybe my concept of using v2 is wrong? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The `v2` in the URL does not refer to your APIs version number, it is the Swagger specification version number.  The current version of SpringFox uses Swagger 2.0 by default, this is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `/v2/api-docs` URL is the default that SpringFox uses for documentation.  The `v2` does not refer to your API's documentation version (which can be changed in the `Docket` configuration), but the version of the Swagger specification being used.   Take a look at the [documentation here](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#customizing-the-swagger-endpoints) for customizing the Swagger documentation URL.  In short, you need to modify an environment property to change the URL your documentation will appear at:

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/my/docs
```

This will change the default URL for the SpringFox Swagger documentation from `/v2/api-docs` to whatever you specify.  To implement this, add the above property to a new or existing properties file, and then add it as a property source in your Springfox configuration class:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {...}
```

Comment: Thanks!. So, this is the endpoint for the swagger documentation only? is not for my API's documentation? how can I set my api's documentation then?

Comment: Swagger is a specification for describing API endpoints.  What you see at `/v2/api-docs` is the documentation for your API in the Swagger 2.0 standard (as opposed to Swagger 1.0, RAML, RestDocs, etc).  You can find more info about the Swagger spec on their website: [http://swagger.io/](http://swagger.io/)

Comment: any idea where my API's docs will be if not in v2/api-docs? (because that URL is already taken) will swagger2 generate or give me an URL for it?

Comment: The Swagger docs are located at whatever the value of the `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path` property is, which is `/v2/api-docs` by default.  See the updated answer above.

Comment: but not for the swagger, for my API, I want to have docs for my API itself, where should they be located?

Comment: I am not totally sure what you are asking for at this point.  The docs generated by Springfox ARE the documentation for your API.  You can change the endpoint for the docs, as I illustrated in my answer.  What that custom endpoint is is completely up to you.  If you are having trouble with a separate aspect of the documentation, perhaps you should create another question and link to it.

Comment: Is there any solution to change the path for /swagger-ui.html?

Comment: @ShikhaA: Swagger UI is a totally separate package with different configuration.

Comment: what does the endpoint should return, if I change it to `/my/docs`? Can I return my own swagger.json?

Comment: I want to return my own generated swagger.json to be displayed by springfox's swagger-ui.html. Is that achievable with this approach? I did the same thing mentioned here and created an endpoint that returns my own swagger.json as string but swagger-ui still displays APIs that aren't those I am returning... I can see the path is changed to /my/docs but it doesn't initiate my endpoint

Comment: @xbmono Have you modified the URL that `swagger-ui` is reading from? You should be able to pint it to your custom URL to read that new json file.

Comment: @woemler No I didn't want to mess with that html file... I fixed it another way, I ended up creating a new bean `SwaggerResourcesProvider` and only returning my swagger's location. This link: http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#aggregating-multiple-swagger-specifications-in-the-same-swagger-ui