# How to export swagger.json (or yaml)

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

How can I export a Swagger definition file? It should be a JSON or YAML file, e.g. swagger.json or swagger.yaml.

Let's say I have an endpoint looking like `http://example.com//swagger/ui/index#!`:

[image]

The version is `api version: v1`.

There is no "Export" button that I can see. So how do I export it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is v2/api-docs the default URL when using springfox and Swagger2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401010/why-is-v2-api-docs-the-default-url-when-using-springfox-and-swagger2)

Comment: No, I think the accepted answer below answers my question. Also the title asks something completely different. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The URL of the API definiton is displayed in the top bar of Swagger UI – in your example it's

```
/v2/api-docs?group=full-petstore-api
```

So the full URL appears to be

```
http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs?group=full-petstore-api
```

In newer versions of Swagger UI, the link to the API definition is often displayed below the API title, so you can right-click the link and Save As.

[image: Link to API definition in Swagger UI 3.x]

If your Swagger UI does not have a visible link to the API definition, view the page source and look for the `url` parameter, such as:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",     // <-------
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
```

If you don't see the `url` or if `url` is a code expression, open the browser dev tools, switch to the **Network** tab and disable caching. Then refresh the page and search for the API definition file (`swagger.json`, `swagger.yaml`, `api-docs` or similar) among HTTP requests. You can filter by **XHR** to narrow down the list.

[image: Finding the Swagger file on the Network tab of browser dev tools]

Another way to find the actual `url` is to use the browser console and evaluate one of the following values, depending on your UI version:

- Swagger UI 3.x:

  ```
  ui.getConfigs().url
  ```
- Swagger UI 2.x:

  ```
  swaggerUi.api.url
  ```

[image]

Sometimes the OpenAPI definition may be embedded within a .js file – in this case take this file and strip out the extra parts.

[image: OpenAPI definition embedded in a JavaScript file]

Comment: In new swagger version ("swagger": "2.0"), you have in network trace "v1", "v2" and not "swagger.json",...  right-click and open it in a new tab, you can see the json with the url : https:// yourapi.yourdomain.com/api/swagger/docs/v2

Comment: @maliness There's no "new Swagger version" because Swagger is not a single tool but a collective name for several tools (editor, UI, codegen and others). That said, the URL depends on how your app is designed, what framework you use, and other things. The URL is not necessarily `/api/swagger/docs/v2`, it can be pretty much anything. Use the **XHR** filter in the dev tools to find the link to your API definition file.

Comment: thanks @Helen. How can we publish this json to a public location, let us say one drive link or a blob storage?

Comment: do you know to edit the JSON in the link that swagger generated?

Comment: @Sattar This depends on whether the API definition is generated from the source code or written/maintained manually. In the former case, you would have to edit the API's source code and re-deploy the API. In the latter case, edit the API definition file in your editor of choice (e.g. https://editor.swagger.io) and then re-upload the file to where it's hosted.

Comment: Hello I wonder if I can get all those files in a list using java ?

Comment: For version 3: http://localhost:1000/v3/api-docs.yaml

Answer (score 25):

Though it's already been answered and it's the correct one, I thought I shall post the much detailed version of it.. Hope this helps,

1. If you do have the swagger json file which you feed to the swagger UI, then to generate .yaml file just click on the below link copy-paste your json in the editor and download the yaml file. This is a straight forward method

link : https://editor.swagger.io/#

2. Now the second way where you don't have any swagger json file then the following steps should help,

Open the swagger ui, inspect (Shift+Ctrl+i), refresh the page and  you will get the tabs like below

[image]

Choose **XHR** or All tab under **Network** tab, check for the file **api-doc?group=*** and click subtab **response**. *Now copy the content of ap-doc?group.** file and use the same editor link to convert to yaml file

link : https://editor.swagger.io/#

Answer (score 8):

The JSON may also be inlined in the document, specifically for Swagger version 2.0. If you haven't found anything after walking through @Helen's answer give this a try:

1. View Page Source
2. Search for `"swagger"` or `"spec"`

If you see a `<script type="application/json">` tag with something similar to the following in it, this is effectively your `swagger.json` content. Copy everything inside of the `<script>` tags and save into a file named swagger.json and you should be good to go.

```
<script id="swagger-data" type="application/json">
{"spec":{"definitions":{},"info":{},"paths":{},"schemes":[],"swagger":"2.0"}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Django Rest Framework (so `pip` package `django-rest-swagger==2.2.0`) and the above answers weren't really sufficient. There were two options:

1) View the page source with developer tools. When I hit my `http://localhost:8000/docs/` endpoint, I see:

[image]

The `docs/` endpoint was configured in Django, so it may be different for you. When digging into the details of that, I can go to the Response tab (in Chrome) and scroll down to find the actual JSON. It's the value in `window.drsSpec`

[image]

2) The alternative (and perhaps easier) approach is to add `?format=openapi` to my endpoint, as suggested in https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/590

This will directly spit out the JSON you need. I imported it into Postman by changing the `swagger` field to `openapi` which seems a little hacky but it worked ‍♂️

Comment: I got .json using that but getting error while importing json to postman "Error while importing: format not recognized". Any Idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If the url is `/api` then to get the json make it `/api-json`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue.

Steps followed:
Enabled root level debug logs and analysed the log messages.

```
o.s.w.a.OpenApiWebfluxResource:
    {GET /v3/api-docs, produces [application/json]}: openapiJson(ServerHttpRequest,String,Locale)
    {GET /v3/api-docs.yaml, produces [application/vnd.oai.openapi]}: openapiYaml(ServerHttpRequest,String,Locale)
```

By looking at the above log, the Api specification yaml file was downloaded by hitting the URL http://server:port/v3/api-docs.yaml

Answer (score 0):

for

> Swashbuckel.aspnet.core(5.5.0)

try

```
services.AddControllers()
                    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

I tried this for a Web API core Project

you have to be using

> System.Text.Json.Serialization;

Answer (score 0):

1. Visit http://localhost:49846/swagger/docs/v1
2. The above URL will return JSON. Save the JSON as swagger.json

Please replace the port number with your port number.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using JUnit test case in compile time, follow https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1959 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 3 , we can use below url to get swagger json :
**http://localhost:8080/<**contextPath**>/v3/api-docs**