# how to describe parameters of Data Type Array[] in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

How do I pass an array object to a parameter in swagger UI? This is a GET request.
I have a request parameter of Data Type: Array[] and Parameter Type: query.
I have tried with below arrays and it doesnt seem to work. I am not familiar with Swagger usage. Unable to figure out the issue.

```
["dataType": 1,"value": "test","orderid": 1]
[1,1 , 1, 1]
[{1,1 , 1, 1}]
[{"dataType": 1,"value": "test","orderid": 1}]
[ dataType: 1]
```

Model:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public int DataType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this OAS 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: Can you post the Swagger definition (YAML or JSON) of your service? See [How to export a Swagger JSON/YAML file from Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is include the object definition in the `components` section (`schema` subsection) and then use the `$ref` keyword to link to the schema under `items:`.

Here is quick example I worked up using the parameters you describe:

example:

Schema:

```
components:
  schemas:
    itemModel:
      properties:
        dataType:
          type: integer
        value:
          type: string
        orderType:
          type: integer
    requestParam:
      properties:
        orders:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/requestParam'
```

Definition:

```
    paths:
  /pets:
    post:
      summary: Add a new pet

      requestBody:
        description: Optional description in *Markdown*
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/requestParam'
```

Another example (bullet point 3)
http://blog.restcase.com/6-most-significant-changes-in-oas-3-0/

Comment: @Kar Sorry, I don't follow.  ui?

Comment: Uploaded the screenshot here imgur.com/BCgnUq8 @taylor-ackley

Comment: What does the swagger definition look like though?