# How to import an existing OpenAPI definition to SwaggerHub?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swaggerhub

Is there a way to import an existing OpenAPI (Swagger) definition to SwaggerHub by providing a link to the corresponding Swagger UI page?

I tried importing the WEBLOC file link that I have, but SwaggerHub does not seem to be able to access it.

[image: Import to SwaggerHub]

Answer (score 0):

To import an API definition into SwaggerHub, you need to specify an URL that points to the YAML or JSON definition file (not to the Swagger UI web page!). For example:

```
http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml
```

Or you can upload the actual YAML or JSON file.

You cannot upload a .webloc file. Open your .webloc in a browser to see where it points to, find out the URL of the API definition file, and use that with SwaggerHub. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116) explains how to get the API definition path from Swagger UI.