# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL

Tags: .net-core, swagger, ocelot

I'm using MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot for gateway. in .Net core

[image]

I got this error. Any idea?

My Upstream and DownStream:

```
"SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "skIndustry",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "Industry API",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "http://industryapi:80/swagger/v1/swagger.json"

        }
      ]
    }
]
```

My ReRoutes:

```
"ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "industryapi/",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Industry/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT", "GET" ],
      "SwaggerKey": "skIndustry"
    }
]
```

Thanks,
Croos.

Comment: Please post the contents of your OpenAPI definition file (YAML / JSON). There should be a link to under the API title at the top ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525934/113116)). If the OpenAPI file is generated from source code, please also post your code.

Comment: Hi (I'm autor of MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot), which version are you use? Please can you provide your ocelot configuration and downstream service original swagger.json? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mino,
Im using MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot 1.2.0. And Json files are Updated in my question.

Comment: @Mino Can you please validate this issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772540/request-url-error-in-swagger-for-ocelot-like-http-http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try new version **1.3.1**.

[This PR probably solve similar problem.](https://github.com/Burgyn/MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot/pull/32)