# Swagger generate static html documentation not using manual yaml spec

Tags: java, maven, swagger

i use swagger:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and i add two seperate /api/docs to it with:

```
@Component
@Primary
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DocumentationController implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {
    @Override
    public List get() {
        List resources = new ArrayList<>();
        resources.add(swaggerResource("dictionary", "/dictionary/v2/api-docs", "2.0"));
        resources.add(swaggerResource("gateway", "/v2/api-docs", "2.0"));
        return resources;
    }

    private SwaggerResource swaggerResource(String name, String location, String version) {
        SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
        swaggerResource.setName(name);
        swaggerResource.setLocation(location);
        swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion(version);
        return swaggerResource;
    }
}
```

I can access it on

http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=gateway

or:

http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=dictionary

Now i want to generate static html documentation from it using this site or

http://localhost:8081/v2/api-docs

How can i do it?
I read about code-gen but i read that it have some yaml spec which i don't have and do not want to write manually.

**Edit:**

If i save json file from content of: http://localhost:8081/v2/api-docs
Is it valid json input file swagger-codegen? Also does this api-docs contains `dictionary` definition also? I would like to trim access to `dictionary` API while reading it (using `MavenXpp3Reader` following snippet here: https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/04/14/microservices-api-documentation-with-swagger2/), and make `HTML` only on the gateway `API` with added additional trimed APIs like `dictionary`.

I want to generate single documentation with many APIs inside, not multiple documentations.

Comment: Tip: If you have Swagger UI, you also have an OpenAPI YAML/JSON spec. [How to export OpenAPI JSON/YAML file from Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116)

Comment: If i save json file from content of: http://localhost:8081/v2/api-docs
Is it valid json input file swagger-codegen? Also does this api-docs contains `dictionary` definition also? I would like to trim access to `dictionary` API while reading it (using `MavenXpp3Reader` following snippet here: https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/04/14/microservices-api-documentation-with-swagger2/), and make `HTML` only on the gateway `API` with added additional trimed APIs like `dictionary`.