# How to configure SwaggerUI to properly set the Bearer Token on the header when using the OAuth 2.0 URL to generated token?

Tags: java-8, oauth-2.0, swagger-2.0, apigee, bearer-token

I have Swagger 2 configs set up to connect to our OAuth2 accesstoken URL.
It is able to connect to the URL without issue when connected using the Apigee URL, but when I go to execute the POST request, I get an `Invalid access token` error. (See stack-trace below)

I've verified the URL, client id & secret using curl, and that works. And I've verified that when I use the provided token `-H "Authorization: Bearer ********token*********"` in my curl POST command, that that works correctly.

However, it doesn't appear that I've properly configured Swagger to create the "Bearer" header as it doesn't show up in the curl command displayed in swagger

#### After Authorizing through Swagger:

[image]

#### Manual Curl Command to generate token:

```
curl -k -v -X POST -u *****************:*************** -d "grant_type=client_credentials" https://***********************/oauth/accesstoken
```

#### accesstoken response body:

```
{
  "refresh_token_expires_in" : "0",
  "api_product_list" : "[********, ********]",
  "api_product_list_json" : [ "********", "********" ],
  "organization_name" : "********",
  "developer.email" : "********",
  "token_type" : "BearerToken",
  "issued_at" : "********",
  "client_id" : "************************",
  "access_token" : "************************",
  "application_name" : "********-****-****-****-********",
  "scope" : "",
  "expires_in" : "1799",
  "refresh_count" : "0",
  "status" : "approved"
}
```

#### Successful Manual Curl command to access endpoint:

```
curl -k -v -X POST "https://*********************/start" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer *****************" -d "{}"
```

#### Failing Curl Command generated by swagger:

```
curl -X POST "https://*********************/start" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}"
```

#### Swagger Error Message:

```
{
  "fault": {
    "faultstring": "Invalid access token",
    "detail": {
      "errorcode": "oauth.v2.InvalidAccessToken"
    }
  }
}
```

#### POM.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

#### Swagger Configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${swagger.host:}")
    private String swaggerHost;

    @Value("${swagger.basePath:}")
    private String swaggerBasePath;

    @Value("${swagger.oauth2.security.schema:oauth2}")
    private String securitySchemaOAuth2;

    @Value("${swagger.oauth2.token.request.url:}")
    private String oauthTokenRequestURL;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host(swaggerHost)
                .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {

                    @Override
                    public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                        return swaggerBasePath;
                    }
                })
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(oauth()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

    private OAuth oauth() {
        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        GrantType creGrant = new ClientCredentialsGrant(oauthTokenRequestURL);

        grantTypes.add(creGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Blah")
                .description("Blah")
                .version("2019.0.1")
                .contact(new Contact("Blah", "", ""))
                .build();
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext
                .builder()
                .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {

        final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[] { authorizationScope };

        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference(securitySchemaOAuth2, authorizationScopes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also post your Swagger YAML/JSON file? See [How to export a Swagger JSON/YAML file from Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116)

Comment: That option is not there. All that's there is the `/api-docs` which I cannot post.
The configs are all annotation driven and provided within the code above, however.