# Can I get Swagger json from a swaggerui url, using Springfox?

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger, springfox

So, I have a spring boot Rest API running (A).

I want to create a separate app(B) which shows the swagger document of A. In order to achieve that I guess I'd have to be able to capture the Swagger json of A, perhaps in a SwaggerResource

> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource

but I don't know how to construct a SwaggerResource object (or similar) from a URL (e.g."http://localhost:9091/swagger-ui.html"). I would have thought this was a trivial enough task, but it has me beat. I'm trying to avoid using eureka.

Comment: See if this helps: [How to export a Swagger JSON/YAML file from Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116)