# Is there a Maven plugin to generate client code from a swagger endpoint?

Tags: spring, rest, swagger, code-generation

I need to consume a REST API created by another team.  They have provided me a swagger-ui endpoint.  I'm coding in Java.  I am using SpringFramework.  I'm looking for something that generates stubs that I can implement and schema classes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) has a [Maven plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin). It can generate Spring server stubs and Java client SDKs among other things.

Codegen has two versions, 3.x and 2.x. They have different `groupId`.

Version [**3.x**](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) is for OpenAPI 3.0 definitions (`openapi: 3.0.x`):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.27</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <configOptions>
                   <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Version [**2.x**](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) is for OpenAPI 2.0 definitions (`swagger: '2.0'`).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.21</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <configOptions>
                   <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For the supported `<language>` values, paste your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file into https://editor.swagger.io and check the values in the "Generate Server" and "Generate Client" menus.

Comment: I believe that this answer is for generating the code for a server from an OpenAPI specified as YAML.  I need to generate the code for a client where I have been given a swagger URL.

Comment: Use `<language>java</language>` or whatever output target you want. All code generators require an OpenAPI YAML/JSON file as input, you can export it from Swagger UI as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116).

Comment: do you understand that I'm trying to generate the client side from a partner's API.  I'll be calling their API.

Comment: `<language>java</language>` generates a Java _client_ SDK. Codegen can generate both servers and clients, the output depends the `<language>` parameter. Some language values indicate servers, others indicate clients.