# MSB3037 openapi2csclient exited with code -1

Tags: swagger, openapi, nswag, autorest

I used Visual Studio Add-Service-Reference to add a service that uses the OpenAPI Specification.
[image: Add service reference]

I input the swagger URL and generated the code.

The .csproj indicates that the service is configured.
[image: service reference]

However when I try to build I get an error.

The wizard contained [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/microsoft.dotnet-openapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) link

The service was generated using AutoRest. I am using VS2022 17.2.5

The full error is

> Error MSB3073 The command
> ""C:\Users\kirst.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.0.5\build../tools/Win/NSwag.exe"
> openapi2csclient /className:myapicls /namespace:myapi
> /input:D:\dev\MyApi\UnitTestProject1\OpenAPIs\index.html
> /output:obj\indexClient.cs " exited with code
> -1.   UnitTestProject1    C:\Users\kirst.nuget\packages\nswag.apidescription.client\13.0.5\build\NSwag.ApiDescription.Client.targets 28

Comment: You probably need to point to an OpenAPI YAML/JSON file, not to the Swagger UI web page. See [How to export OpenAPI YAML/JSON file from Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service reference expects an OpenAPI YAML/JSON document, not the Swagger UI web page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525546/113116) explains how you can find the URL of your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file or export it from Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else ends up here but got the URL correct (usually its /api/swagger.json) there might be a problem with spaces in the path to the project. I started to have this problem after checking out a project to another machine.

The fix was in the file
C:\Users\{user}\.nuget\packages\nswag.apidescription.client\13.0.5\build\NSwag.ApiDescription.Client.targets

in Line 21:

```
    <Command>%(Command) /input:%(FullPath) /output:%(OutputPath) %(Options)</Command>
```

To make swagger whitespace compatible, change that line to:

```
    <Command>%(Command) /input:"%(FullPath)" /output:"%(OutputPath)" %(Options)</Command>
```

Error is gone after that