# convert swagger to postman with JSON that gotten from swagger-ui-init.js

Tags: postman, swagger

I want to use swagger that already deployed in the server.
in most tutorials I saw that they used link from swagger header but I don't have it.

[image]

using link (http://95.216.161.15:30400/api-docs/) tab `link` will return this:

`Error while importing: format not recognized`

---

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525546/how-to-export-swagger-json-or-yaml#:%7E:text=Sometimes%20the%20OpenAPI%20definition%20may%20be%20embedded%20within%20a%20.js%20file%20%E2%80%93%20in%20this%20case%20take%20this%20file%20and%20strip%20out%20the%20extra%20parts.) that says I can use `swagger-ui-init.js` for extracting JSON from in it.

Now I have this

[image]

when I importing It as OpenAPI it will return this:

`Error while importing: format not recognized`

what should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need just this part, without the trailing comma.

[image]