# Unable To Send Bearer Token in Authorization Header In Swagger-ui-express npm

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am running an `express`/node application and am documenting my api using `"swagger-ui-express": "^4.5.0",`. I have set up a requirement of needing a `jsonwebtoken` bearer token to be sent with all requests to any endpoint in my api.

I have the swagger docs loaded and working properly but now when trying to figure out how to pass the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` to all my endpoints, it doesn't seem to work. I am able to add the `securitySchemes` + child options and I get the green `Authorize` button in my swagger docs, but when I enter a bearer token and send off the request the loading spinner keeps spinning and never sends the request. I have `morgan` logging set up in my app so I can see that the request to my endpoint never gets sent or logged.

How do I send a bearer token to requests sent from swagger UI?

In app.js I have this route which loads properly in localhost

```
// Single entry point for swagger docs
router.use(
  '/swaggerDocs',
  swaggerDoc.serve,
  swaggerDoc.setup(swaggerDocumentation),
);
```

`swaggerDocumentation` from above snippet (config file).

```
import getCountryRegions from './getCountryRegions.doc.js';

export default {
  openapi: '3.0.3',
  info: {
    title: 'Node/express rest api app',
    version: '0.0.1',
  },
  components: {
    securitySchemes: {
      bearerAuth: {
        type: 'http',
        in: 'header',
        name: 'Authorization',
        description: 'Bearer Token',
        scheme: 'bearer',
        bearerFormat: 'JWT',
      },
    },
  },
  security: {
    bearerAuth: [],
  },
  servers: [
    {
      url: 'http://localhost:3010/api',
      description: 'Local server',
    },
  ],
  paths: {
    ...getCountryRegions,
  },
};
```

Modal to enter bearer token
[image]

Adding token
[image]

Request is sent but it spins endlessly without ever sending the request
[image]

No errros in my application terminal or logging but I do see one error in the chrome browser console when sending the request:
[image]

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Hi @Anatoly I added more info to my question. I actually do see an error in the console that does not stem from my code directly. Seems to be an issue with something in Swagger?

Comment: [Export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525934/113116) your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file from Swagger UI and then paste its contents into https://editor.swagger.io. Does the editor flag any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the issue...the `security` property has to have an `[]` wrapped around it's object.

```
components: {
    securitySchemes: {
      bearerAuth: {
        type: 'http',
        in: 'header',
        name: 'Authorization',
        description: 'Bearer token to access these api endpoints',
        scheme: 'bearer',
        bearerFormat: 'JWT',
      },
    },
  },
  security: [
    {
      bearerAuth: [],
    },
  ],
```

This chunk of code works.