# execute button in swagger ui (openapi ui) is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am implementing OpenAPI Swagger UI, but execute button on service invocation block is not working or when clicked on the button, no action is performed. how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: 1) Are there any errors in the browser console? 2) [Export your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525934/113116) from Swagger UI and paste it into https://editor.swagger.io - does the editor flag any syntax errors?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized?