# How to change default Swagger 2 api doc name in Java Spring API

Tags: java, spring, swagger

So right now the default is: `/v2/api-doc` .

How can I configure swagger to be `/v2/swagger.json`

I don't know how to find the property file.

Solution is on the comments in .yml file :

```
springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger:
      v2:
       path: /v1/swagger.json
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is v2/api-docs the default URL when using springfox and Swagger2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401010/why-is-v2-api-docs-the-default-url-when-using-springfox-and-swagger2)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Springfox :

> You can point users that want to generate code based on your swagger spec to /v2/api-docs.
>   When you don't like what you're seeing, don't worry, this can be changed too.
>   Add the property springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path to the application.properties file of your application and
>   set its value to any path you'd like the docs to be available on.

Answer (score 0):

`/v2/api-doc` is default url.

To add your custom url add following in propertyfile

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/my/path
```

Comment: which dependency did you add? my .yml file isn't picking it up

Comment: sorry to bother you, how to you turn pretty print on ?

Comment: I guess its http.mappers.jsonPrettyPrint=true