# Swagger UI hide api-docs URL

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using Springfox 2.9.2 for Swagger UI.

Is it possible to hide the */v2/api-docs* URL from the swagger-ui.html title, using the Docket in the Configuration class?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find how to hide it but you can change it to whatever you want. 
[Why is v2/api-docs the default URL when using springfox and Swagger2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401010/why-is-v2-api-docs-the-default-url-when-using-springfox-and-swagger2)